# tcpdf custom HTML header with image

Tags: html, image, codeigniter, header, tcpdf

I am trying to create a custom html header for my tcpdf library in codeigniter.

I have currently got the below syntax (libraries/Pdf.php) which works and displays perfectly. I do however want to replace 'image here' with an image which is where I am having a problem.

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    var $htmlHeader="
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    image here
    </td>
    <td>second cell
    </td></tr></table>
    sample text
    <hr>
   ";

    public function setHtmlHeader($htmlHeader) {
        $this->htmlHeader = $htmlHeader;
    }

    public function Header() {
        $this->writeHTMLCell(
            $w = 0, $h = 0, $x = '', $y = '',
            $this->htmlHeader, $border = 0, $ln = 1, $fill = 0,
            $reseth = true, $align = 'top', $autopadding = true);
    }

}
```

I have tried several options:
 - a url path

`<img src="http://domain.com/images/logo.png"/>`

- a relative path

  `<img src="/images/logo.png"/>`
- a path on the server

  `<img src="c:htdocs/images/logo.png"/>`

These all dont work. eighter just white space and the rest of pdf is correct or the entire pf breaks and is just a white screen with no output errors.

what else can I try?

there is this int he tcpdf examples:

```
$image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'logo_example.jpg';
        $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 15, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
```

but I cant seem to use that in my customer pdf class and have no idea how to get that into my html.

Help welcome as always.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found this

http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/create-pdf-documents-online-with-tcpdf/

hope can help you. Sorry if this post suppose to post as comment because I can't post comment.